# Adding an onClick to image with Jquery fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a link on am image that I include dynamically with this jQuery:

```
//Add back button code onclick
$("#backLocation").replaceWith("<a href=\"#\"  ><img id=\"backClick\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" src=\"img/back.png\" height=\"30\" width=\"30\"> </a>");
```

I then set the onCLikc event for the link with:

```
$("#backClick").on('click', function (e) {
                //go back a page
                parent.history.back();

            });
```

But it does not go to the previous page.

I am not sure if its because its a locally hosted web app or what, or If I have just structured something wrong. In the adress bar the page just changes from:

page.html   to page.html#   when I click the back image link I cerated.

Comment: post your html code.

Comment: .on structure is `$(document).on(action, selector, function() {});`

Comment: Are you using ***base href***? if yes use `preventDefault()`. ***base href*** may cause redirect before even the javascript or jquery code is called.

Comment: And why are you not give the a the id instead of the image? You also want to use nikhil recommendation `window.history.back();` instead of `parent.history.back();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper .on structure is `$(document).on(action, selector, function() {});`

Also, you are click an href, which will tell the browser to navigate to a page, then move back a page, resulting in no action being taken. Try adding `preventDefault`.

I would also suggest accessing the window to go backward in history.

```
$(document).on('click', "#backClick", function (e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     e.preventDefault(); 
     window.history.back();
});
```

Adding window.event will allow for support on IE 8 and older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your click binding to following

```
$(document).on('click', "#backClick", function (e) {
     //go back a page
     parent.history.back();

});
```

Comment: It ought to work. Try add console.log. Earlier, there must be no logging coming in console and now it will come up. Additionally, you are using `parent.history.back()` - are you using iframes?

Comment: Just through an alert in there. Looks like the onClick works but the back does not.

Comment: Then in place of `parent.history.back()` use `history.back()`

Comment: Well then it seems you are doing something unusual. Can you reproduce the issue anywhere in plunker/fiddle or you can also mail me the same